# How to select records only when the SUM(field) from a separate table > 0 using MAX to identify the most recent 'field'

Tags: mysql, select, sum, max

I have been battling with this query for over a day now. My SQL is not amazing, so that might explain why! Anyway, I'd really appreciate if anyone could clarify what I'm doing wrong here.

```
CREATE TABLE `business` (
  `business_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
)

CREATE TABLE `business_unit` (
  `business_unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `business_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE `offer` (
  `offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `business_unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `points_required` int(11) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `points_balance` (
  `points_balance_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mobile_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `business_unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `record_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)
```

The data would be:

```
INSERT INTO `business` (`business_id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `business` (`business_id`) VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO `business_unit` (`business_unit_id`,`business_id`) VALUES (11, 1);
INSERT INTO `business_unit` (`business_unit_id`,`business_id`) VALUES (12, 1);
INSERT INTO `business_unit` (`business_unit_id`,`business_id`) VALUES (13, 2);
INSERT INTO `business_unit` (`business_unit_id`,`business_id`) VALUES (14, 2);

INSERT INTO `offer` (`offer_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points_required`) VALUES (21, 11, 50);
INSERT INTO `offer` (`offer_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points_required`) VALUES (22, 12, 50);
INSERT INTO `offer` (`offer_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points_required`) VALUES (23, 12, 60);
INSERT INTO `offer` (`offer_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points_required`) VALUES (24, 13, 100);
INSERT INTO `offer` (`offer_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points_required`) VALUES (25, 14, 30);
INSERT INTO `offer` (`offer_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points_required`) VALUES (26, 14, 150);

INSERT INTO `points_balance` (`points_balance_id`,`user_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points`,`record_created`) VALUES (31, 27, 11, 10, '2013-04-01');
INSERT INTO `points_balance` (`points_balance_id`,`user_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points`,`record_created`) VALUES (32, 27, 11, 30, '2013-04-02');
INSERT INTO `points_balance` (`points_balance_id`,`user_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points`,`record_created`) VALUES (33, 27, 12, 10, '2013-03-02');
INSERT INTO `points_balance` (`points_balance_id`,`user_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points`,`record_created`) VALUES (34, 27, 12, 20, '2013-03-04');
INSERT INTO `points_balance` (`points_balance_id`,`user_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points`,`record_created`) VALUES (34, 27, 14, 20, '2013-04-12');
INSERT INTO `points_balance` (`points_balance_id`,`user_id`,`business_unit_id`,`points`,`record_created`) VALUES (34, 27, 14, 100, '2013-04-14');
```

*Records in the points balance table are insert only, so the user's balance for a unit is on the most recent record for that user/unit*

*Business units within the same business share the points balance (i.e. a user's total points is the sum of their points on the various units within that business).*

I want to select offers where the user has enough points to redeem them.

```
SELECT up.user_id, up.points, o.*
FROM offer o
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, business_id, sum(points) AS points 
    FROM points_balance pb
    JOIN business_unit bu on pb.business_unit_id = bu.business_unit_id
    WHERE pb.points_balance_id IN (
        SELECT MAX(pb2.points_balance_id)
        FROM points_balance pb2
        WHERE pb2.user_id = 27
        GROUP BY pb2.business_unit_id)
    GROUP BY user_id, business_id
) up ON up.points >= o.points_required
```

The query above is returning one instance of the same offer multiple times (times the number of business the user has points at) :(

**The result set I'm looking for is:**

```
user_id | points    | offer_id
27      |   50      |  21
27      |   50      |  22
27      |   100     |  24
27      |   100     |  25
```

Thanks all.
G

Comment: first off it needs to be totally revamped. never write an "in (" clause unless it is like "in (1,2,3)" sort of thing

Comment: I'm sure the query can be improved (or totally rewritten!). Regarding your comment, the result of the sub-queries inside the IN() is a comma separated list of IDs. Do you mean, it's not a good idea to have a sub-query inside an IN()?

Comment: correct. fine for tables of 10 rows while you are learning. after that it is dog slow. then you will have to learn joins

Comment: i think you need to slowly look at the data you provided and the results you want. it is messed up i think.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong there. The results I want should be offers from units within Business the user has points at. The 'points' column the result contains the total of points the user has at each Business (which is the SUM of points across the businesses' units).

Comment: sorry i dont work for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was returning multiple instances of the same offer when I had points to redeem the offer in multiple business. So the problem is that I was not linking the offer to the specific business! so I added to the bottom of the query

```
JOIN business_unit bu ON bu.business_unit_id = o.business_unit_id
AND up.business_id = bu.business_id
```

Sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that does what I think you want:

```
select up.user_id, up.business_id, up.allpoints, o.*
from (select user_id, business_id, sum(points_balance) as allpoints
      from points_balance pb join
           business_Unit bu
           on pb.business_unit_id = bu.business_unit_id
      group by user_id, business_id
     ) up join
     offers o
     on o.point_required <= up.allpoints;
```

The logic behind this query is much simpler than the approach you were taking.  The first subquery calculates the total number of points available for a user across all business units within a business.  It then finds the matching points.

You can add `where` clauses either in the subquery or in the overall query to limit to particular businesses or users.

Also, this is based on the field names in the text of the question, not the ones in the query.  They are different.

Comment: Thaks Gordon. I have added a WHERE clause to restrict to a specific user and the results look better already. The only problem at the moment is that the offers are returned multiple times (e.g. if the user has points in 5 business, each offer is returned * 5. I believe I need to set another WHERE clause somewhere to stop it.